# How to get the value in an array in default.rb in the recipe?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

In `attributes/default.rb`, values are declared in below format.

```rb
default[:node][:action][:host_list] = [
  {
    :environment => 'dev',
    :application => 'appA',
    :server_name => 'serverA',
    :url => 'serverA.com'
  },
  {
    :environment => 'dev',
    :application => 'appB',
    :server_name => 'serverB',
    :url => 'serverB.com'
  },
  {
    :environment => 'test',
    :application => 'appA',
    :server_name => 'tserverA',
    :url => 'tserverA.com'
  },
  {
    :environment => 'test',
    :application => 'appB',
    :server_name => 'tserverB',
    :url => 'tserverB.com'
  }
]
```

From one of my recipes, how to retrieve the value of `server_name` and `url` (as reqd) from this `default.rb`?

I get env & app values from the data bag. I need the other values like server_name & url for using for eg. in a simple puts statement & a http invocation respectively.

Example:

:environment = dev & :application = appA (values read from databag)

I need the corresponding :server_name and :url from the host_list declaration in the default.rb so that the I get the values like below:

```rb
full_server_name = [:env]-[:app]-[:server_name] #=> dev-appA-serverA

puts :url #=> serverA.com
```

Comment: Try this `host_list = node[:node][:action][:host_list]
host_list.each do |host|
  puts "Server Name: #{host[:server_name]}"
  puts "URL: #{host[:url]}"
end`

Comment: *From one of my recipes* — it is unclear what do you want. Which one? What did you try?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do? Please add to your question an example of what the output data is that you expect to retrieve.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. By From one of my recipes I mean the main recipe where I need to read these values from default.rb. The output I need is the server name & URL depending on the environment & application.

Comment: @Venky That response is not helpful. Add to your original post an actual example of what you are trying to achieve, e.g., *"Given two variables `example_env = 'test'` and `example_app = 'appb'` I need code that will return a hash that looks like `{ :server_name => 'tserverB', :url => 'tserverB.com' }` or an array that looks like `[{ :server_name => 'tserverB', :url => 'tserverB.com' }]`."*

Comment: @anothermh I will put it this way. I get env & app values from the data bag.  I need the other values like server_name & url for using for eg. in a simple puts statement & a http invocation respectively.
I have env = dev & app = appA, I need the corresponding :server_name and :url so that the I get the values like in below eg.
full_server_name = [:env]-[:app]-[:server_name] (dev-appA-serverA)
puts :url (serverA.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `.select` Ruby method to find the matching values from the (array of) Hashes and store it in variables. Then we can use these variables to form the expected output.

As shown in your question for example, let's have `:environment` as `dev`, and `:application` as `appA` from databag.

```rb
env = 'dev'
app = 'appA'

# first variable captures (two) hashes that have environment dev
r1 = node[:node][:action][:host_list].select {|r| r[:environment] == env}

# next variable collects the hash which contains appA
r2 = r1.select {|r| r[:application] == app}

# we can now use values from r2
full_server_name = "#{r2[0][:environment]}-#{r2[0][:application]}-#{r2[0][:server_name]}"

puts r2[0][:url]
```

Note that we have to use the array index `0` since your original attribute is an array of Hashes.